# CSS for visited page

Tags: html, css

I am building a website based on wordPress theme. Whenever I visited any page its giving me red underline border at current page.From last 2 days I am trying but cant delete this underline. 
I tried 
1. visited -> border-bottom-color, 
2. target->  border-bottom-color,
3. current->

but nothing works. I cant get the code to modify through 'inspect' the page.
Any advice will be very highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you put some example code in jsFiddle or something.

Comment: Have to tried 'outline-color' ?. Update your question with image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Css,

```
ul.nav > li.current > a:before, .page ul.nav > li.current-menu-item > 
a:before, .single-post ul.nav > li.current-menu-item > a:before, .archive 
ul.nav > li.current-menu-item > a:before
{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 12.5%;
  width: 75%;
  height: 2px;
  margin: auto;
  background: transparent;
  content: "";
}
```

Comment: I am sure the problem is this backgroung color. But, i am not about the class name.

Comment: Thanks again Sakkeer